# Access modifiers for inner classes

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [protected/public Inner Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595179/protected-public-inner-classes)

I am sure the question has been asked already, but I wasn't able to find one so I'll ask...

I am curious what is the difference between private(protected) and public inner class. I am able to use both from out of the containing class using the outer class object.

```
public class A{
   private class B{

   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
     A a = new A();
     B b = a.new B();
   }
}
```

Comment: is it allowed to use `a.new B()` in java?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Yes, that is how one instantiates a non-static inner class in Java.

Comment: Also allowed to use the short form new A().new B()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A private inner class can still be accessed within the class that defined it.

If you have another class, `B` isn't visible:

```
public class C {
   public static void main(String[] args){
     A a = new A();
     B b = new B(); // compile error
   }
}
```

Comment: This is already the case, as B isn't static...

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you are inside class A still, since the main method is a static method of class A